# NVIDIA DALI : unable to load videos using readers.video in NVIDIA DALI pipeline

Tags: nvidia, video-processing, video-capture, dali

Trying to load the video for NVIDIA DALI pipeline for video processing but not able to load the .mp4 video.

```
import os
import numpy as np    
from nvidia.dali import pipeline_def
import nvidia.dali.fn as fn
import nvidia.dali.types as types       

batch_size=2
sequence_length=8
initial_prefetch_size=16 

video_directory=['sintel_trailer-720p_0.mp4']
n_iter=6

print(video_directory)


@pipeline_def
def video_pipe(file_root):
    video, labels = fn.readers.video(device="gpu", file_root=file_root, sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                     random_shuffle=True, initial_fill=initial_prefetch_size)
    return video, labels


pipe = video_pipe(batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2, device_id=0, file_root=video_directory, seed=12345)
pipe.build()
```

Above DALI pipeline shows the following issue while loading the video:

> RuntimeError: Critical error when building pipeline: Error when
> constructing operator: readers__Video encountered:
> [/opt/dali/dali/operators/reader/loader/video_loader.cc:117] Assert on
> "dir != nullptr" failed: Directory ['sintel_trailer-720p_0.mp4'] could
> not be opened.

I have referred the documentation from NVIDIA DALI for video processing but not to able solve,

Please check for reference : [NVIDIA DALI DOCS VIDEO PROCESSING](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/examples/sequence_processing/video/video_reader_simple_example.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `file_root` argument points to the root directory, where DALI should search for videos, and the `file_list` argument should point to a file listing all samples to be loaded.

However, from your example, the `filenames` argument must be the one that suits your needs better.

Your example should work as expected, with the following pipeline definition:

```py
@pipeline_def
def video_pipe(file_root):
    video, labels = fn.readers.video(device="gpu", filenames=file_root, labels=[], sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                     random_shuffle=True, initial_fill=initial_prefetch_size)
    return video, labels
```

I added the `labels` argument too. Without it, the operator returns just one output. Please see the [DALI manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/supported_ops.html#nvidia.dali.fn.readers.video) if you want to understand the operator better.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and forum discussion from NVIDIA DALI got this Answer, Please refer to [issues/3503](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DALI/issues/3503) the link for a detailed answer discussion.
Thank you